# dhtmlxGantt - scroll not working when moving task

Tags: javascript, dhtml, dhtmlx, gantt-chart

How can I configure dhtmlxGantt to scroll while moving task out of visible area (left, right).
For example, I try to move task "Marketing" after 20 Apr on this sample

http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxGantt/01_basic.html

it's not working, so there isn't horizontal automatic scrollbar.

Second example with scroll

http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxGantt/05_critical_path.html

I'm trying drag "Documentation creation" task to the right side, but horizontal scroll not working.

Answer (score -1):

The sample pages you provided answer you question. A function get triggered to enable the horizontal scrolling:

Event:

`<body onresize="modHeight()">`

Function:

```
function modHeight(){
        var headHeight = 35;
        var sch = document.getElementById("gantt_here");
        sch.style.height = (parseInt(document.body.offsetHeight)-headHeight)+"px";
        gantt.setSizes();
}
```